# Why use Wget instead of a browser?

Tags: wget, internet, download

When should I use Wget rather than a browser? I heard that Stallman uses it instead of a browser for anonymity reasons. What does the server think/see when you get its files using Wget?

Comment: Please don't crosspost (http://askubuntu.com/questions/821047/why-would-i-use-wget-instead-of-browser).

Comment: Try browsing this site with `wget`, then come back to tell us how well did it go. You shouldn't confuse politics and technicalities, you know.

Answer (score 2):

#### In what case I should prefer use Wget rather than some browser ?

From [the man page of wget](http://man.he.net/?topic=wget&section=all):

> GNU Wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the Web.  It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval through HTTP proxies.
>
> Wget is non-interactive, meaning that it can work in the background, while the user is not logged on.  This allows you to start a retrieval and disconnect from the system, letting Wget finish the work.  By contrast, most of the Web browsers require constant user's presence, which can be a great hindrance when transferring a lot of data.

The good thing about wget is you can use it in command line, or in a script and download file in background.

#### What server thinks/sees when you get its files using Wget ?

They see it as a browser requesting a file just like other browsers.

Here is the header of wget (this is what servers see):

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.18 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: localhost:80
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And here is the header of firefox:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:80
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: zh-TW,en-US;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

As you can see, they are similar.

Comment: "They see it as a browser requesting a file just like other browsers." - I understand that you didn't mean that, but sounds like you wanted to say that server don't recognize Wget, jcoppens said it more clearly: "wget identifies as such, and more than a few site take that as a bad thing".

Comment: The server actually doesn't care what program your using to get it's content, it only cares the requests you send and what should it response. It's even possible to use net cat to get web contents while the server think you are an IE.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the best arguments is that `wget` is capable of retrying if a connection is unreliable, and can even instruct the server to 'reget', to continue download from the point where the previous download failed - which is very welcome when downloading large files. Some browser plugins are capable of this too.

Also, very useful, is that `wget` can download entire directories (including subdirectories), and does so avoiding repetitions in the download.

About anonymity - that is very relative. Normally, `wget` identifies as such, and more than a few site take that as a bad thing - some block wget.

But, it is possible to make `wget` identify as any other string, using the `--user-agent=agent-string` command line option. (Again, similar tricks are possible with some browser plugins)

So, basically, this is a question of taste... A good argument is that `wget` can be used easily in scripts, which is more complicated with browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of features in a graphical browser(`Firefox`, `Chrome`, etc...), they will be used to identify the user.
Not just HTTP headers.
They are called "browser fingerprint".

- Installed plugins
- Current screen resolution
- Installed fonts
- Supported features

and many others...
(reference: [**"Am I unique?"**](https://amiunique.org/), [**"Panopticlick"**](https://panopticlick.eff.org/),
[**"BrowserLeaks.com"**](http://www.browserleaks.com/)
)

CLI browser(`wget`, `curl`, etc...) does not have a lot of these "fingerprint", because these are very simple.
This increases the anonymity, make it difficult to the tracking of the user.